# Не получается получить значения выбора даты через datapicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

[В продолжение темы  datapicker](http://%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20datapicker%20bootstrap) 
Есть блок с возможностью выбора даты и времени, который реализован с помощью `datapicker bootstrap`. [Ссылка на документацию](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/).

Не могу понять, как получать значения инпутов при выборе данных пользователем, т.к. значение *val* получаю только, если ввожу значения вручную, а если нажимаю на стрелочку и выбираю через датапикер, то значение в инпуте не задается - почему и как можно решить?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD MMMM',
    locale: 'ru'
  });
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'HH'
  });
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'mm'
  });
});

$('.datetimepicker-input').on('click', function() {
  let $data = $(this).val();
  console.log($data);
});

$('.input-group-append').on('click', function() {
  let target = $(this).data('target');
  console.log(target);
});

$('#datetimepicker3').on('click', function() {
  console.log("click datetimepicker3");
  let data = $(this).find('.datetimepicker-input').val();
  console.log(data);
});
```

```css
.input-group .form-control {
  border-right: none;
}

.input-group .input-group-text {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.datetimepicker-input {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Дата</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker3" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker3" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker3" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Время</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker2" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Вот так отлавливаются изменения

```
  $('#datetimepicker3').on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
      var input = $(this).find('.datetimepicker-input').val();
      console.log(input);
   });
```